# Why there is a 0.0.0.0 gateway for eth0 if I only add one in the interface config?

Tags: networking, gateway

In my interface config file, I only add one route for the 192.168.2.0, but when the machine is running, there is a 0.0.0.0 gateway for 192.168.2.0.

How to fix this only using interface config?

```
$ route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         10.164.0.1      0.0.0.0         UG    600    0        0 wlan0
10.164.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     600    0        0 wlan0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 eth0
192.168.2.0     192.168.2.101   255.255.255.0   UG    0      0        0 eth0
192.168.2.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
202.161.42.25   10.164.0.1      255.255.255.255 UGH   600    0        0 wlan0
$ cat /etc/network/interfaces
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
    address 192.168.2.102
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    up route add -net 192.168.2.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 gw 192.168.2.101
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by adding the `up route ...` line?

Comment: `eth0` on my computer is linked to a hub(or just two computers linked by a cable) without dhcp, I have to add a gateway and static ip.

Comment: And where did you see that this was the correct way to do it? (It isn't.)

Comment: If I just add static ip, the network 192.168.2.0 is unreachable, so I added the `up route` , after which it's reachable, but I just don't get it why there's a 0.0.0.0 gateway generated? If there's a better way, I definitely will avoid adding the route.